# How to parametrize JMeter Loop Controller with Groovy function?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am pretty new to Jmeter but can handle "simple" test plans. I really do need help with the issue I am facing. Currently I run into a problem regarding how to parametrize the Loop Controller loop count Groovy function.

I did found a lot of examples but they are all with static loop count like: ${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().size(),)}.
I really would like to parametrize the part 'test.csv'. Therefor I replaced that with ${csvFile}, like:

```
${__groovy(new File(${csvFile}).readLines().size(),)}.
```

In the 'User Defined Variables' section of the 'Test Plan' I created the variable 'csvFile'.
[Test plan image in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbtbN.png)

When I execute the script I retrieve an error in the log like:

```
2022-01-25 11:35:14,870 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script16.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '\' @ line 1, column 12.
   new File(D:\devenv\projecten\JM_InterestDeterminationService\inputmessages.csv).readLines().size()
              ^

1 error
```

Is the error pointing to the backslash? Is that because of the Windows OS?

Must I replace the '\' with a '/'? How and where can I do that?
I started fiddling around with .replaceAll("\\", "/") and .replaceAll("\\\\", "/"), but I don't know where to put it and what the correct syntax is.

Could any of you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of the reasons [why it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler).

Just use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance to read your `csvFile` variable value like:

```
${__groovy(new File(vars.get('csvFile')).readLines().size(),)}
```

and it should resolve your issue.

More information on this and other JMeter API shorthands: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)